# How to write the unit of molar gas constant correctly?

Tags: conventions, units, physical-constants, si-units

Is it $8.314J{mol}^{-1}K^{-1}$ or $8.314JK^{-1}{mol}^{-1}$ or $8.314mol^{-1}K^{-1}J$ or $8.314K^{-1}mol^{-1}J$ or $8.314mol^{-1}JK^{-1}$?

Comment: Operating by the principle of least surprise, you may wish to finish multiplying (8.314 and joules) before you start dividing (moles and kelvins). This will match common use in the literature. Note that SI convention is to insert a space between a number and a unit, so all of these currently lie outside the recommended form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter. All those are equivalent. Basically the reason is the fundamental axiom that the order of factors (terms in a multiplication) doesn't matter. Furthermore a negative exponent corresponds to division, so all those versions correspond to: $$8.314\,\mathrm{J\cdot mol^{-1}\cdot K^{-1}} =8.314\, \mathrm{\frac{J}{mol\cdot K}}. $$